# How do you differentiate between optional field, required invalid field and required valid field?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, validation

How do you differentiate between optional field, required invalid field and required valid field in Angular JS?

The requirement is to have optional fields in white background, required invalid fields in yellow background with red border and required valid fields in yellow background WITHOUT red border.

In my page, ng-required is set dynamically. Even if it is set to false; angular adds class "ng-valid-required". There’s simply no way to differentiate. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="vm.Category" ng-required="vm.IsCategoryRequired">
    <option ng-repeat="option in vm.CategoryOptions" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.label}}</option>
</select>`
```

CSS:

```
select.ng-required {
    background-color: #fdfddf;
}
select.ng-valid-required{
    background-color: #fdfddf;
}
select.ng-invalid {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px rgba(227,43,43,1);
    background-color: #fdfddf;
}
```

The problem is angular puts class ng-valid-required even if vm.IsCategoryRequired = false.
ng-valid-required is absent only when ng-required attribute is absent.

Comment: You need to post some code for someone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided any code, I'll assume that one of your input field would look like this

```
<input ng-modal="myModal" ng-required="a===b" />
```

here `a===b` is the condition (let's say)

Now one way is to specify a condition in `ng-style` like this that will set the background color and border.

```
<input ng-modal="myModal" ng-required="a===b" 
       ng-style="a===b ? { 'background-color':'yellow', 'border': '1px solid red' } : { 'background-color':'yellow', 'border': '1px solid black' }"/>
```